# How can I automate Azure Spark from c#?

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I can create the cluster but how do I then automate scripts?

```
  var clusterInfo = new ClusterCreateParametersV2
            {
                Name = clusterConfig.ClusterName,
                ...
                ClusterType = ClusterType.Spark
            };`
```

`cluster.RunScript()` ?

Can i get a SparkContext?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-use-bi-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Today we use livy server on HDInsight spark cluster on linux.

See documetation here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-livy-rest-interface/